# Including headers and footers from another files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, include

I'm new with ASP.NET, and I want to use a simple technique that I used to do with PHP on a web site. That is, include files to render headers and footes. For example,

```
<?php
    include "header.php";
    echo "Hello, world!";
    include "footer.php";
?>
```

What's the right way to do something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Webforms - you'll want to use [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).

ASP.NET MVC - you'll want to use [partial views](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/638_Understanding_Partial_Views_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx).

A quick note based on one of the other answers - if you're using webforms and using this strictly to use a common header and footer for many pages on your site, then [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) actually would be the best approach in my opinion.  But if you are asking, in general, how to render re-usable blocks of code in an ASP.NET web application, similar to how you use `includes` in php, then user controls / partial views is what you're looking for.

Comment: It's on Webforms and UserControls was my guess indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In a master page register the control:

```
<%@ Register src="~/Controls/Header.ascx" tagname="Header" tagprefix="abc" %>
<%@ Register src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" tagname="Footer" tagprefix="abc" %>
```

And in the master page's body:

```
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="header">
                <abc:Header ID="abcHeader" runat="server" />
            </div> 


            <div id="footer">
                <abc:Footer ID="abcFooter" runat="server" />           
            </div> 
        </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

In php you have to use include() fuction but in asp.net you use the concept of master pages. Using master pages, you dont need to do this. Watch this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epaavQsb950

and also check out this 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHoyxLjcSYA

Answer (score 1):

In normal ASP.NET websites, we achieve it by using User Controls. User Controls are nothing but partial set of controls which can be re-used in many screens. *Header* and *Footer* are the best examples of it. Please go through *[ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)* (MSDN) to know more about user controls and here is [a great walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616.aspx) which explains it in details.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the headers and footers created yet?

If so, what format are they in?

If you are starting from scratch, I would recommend using Master Pages.
*[Creating a Site-Wide Layout Using Master Pages (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs)* gets you started with using Master pages quickly.